# Como agarrar solo el primer y el ultimo digito de un numero x

Tags: python

Escriba un programa para encontrar la suma del primer y último dígito de un número.

```
import math   #Importamos la libreria necesaria
n=int(input('Ingrese un numero ')) #Recogemos valor
x = [(n//(10**i))%10 for i in range(math.ceil(math.log(n, 10))-1, -1, -1)] #separamos cada digito
print(x) #Imprimimos la lista con los digitos
```

no se como tomar el primer y ultimo digito de esa lista para luego sumarlos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para encontrar el primer y último dígito de un numero, se puede hacer de varias maneras, entre ellas:

Usando strings:

```
>>> n = 5638
>>> int(str(n)[0])
5
>>> int(str(n)[-1])
8
```

Usando matemática

```
>>> import math
>>> n // (10 ** int(math.log10(n)))
5
>>> n % 10
8
```

Comment: Para mi sorpresa, el método mas veloz es el primero. Aunque probé con en numero 10**1000 y es más rapido el segundo.

Answer (score -1):

yo si es un número como dice el enunciado, siempre que sea positivo lo haría así:

```
numero=45686 
num = numero%10 
num2=int(str(numero)[0])
print(num2+num)
```

- La primera linea es la variable donde se encuentra el número.
- La segunda linea meto dentro de la variable num el resto de dividir el
  numero entre 10 que es igual al último dígito del número
- La tercera linea, pasamos el numero a string con str() y cogemos el que
  está en la  primera posicion con [0]
- La cuarta  linea  sumamos las dos variables

Comment: Por favor explica que hace tu código y porque responde a la pregunta de OP, considera que habrán bastantes usuarios nuevos que apenas van aprendiendo y no entenderán tu respuesta, lee [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). ;)

Answer (score -2):

Entiendo que solo quieres sacar el primer dígito y el último de la lista y sumarlos, yo lo haría así:

```
>>> sum = x[0]+x[-1]
>>> print(sum)
```

Comment: No hay ninguna lista involucrada. El problema es sumar el primer y último digito de un entero como 32569 -> 3 + 9 = 12

Comment: [Es confuso al mencionar número y lista abajo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/485763/como-agarrar-solo-el-primer-y-el-ultimo-digito-de-un-numero-x/485772?noredirect=1#:~:text=no%20se%20como%20tomar%20el%20primer%20y%20ultimo%20digito%20de%20esa%20lista%20para%20luego%20sumarlos.). La solución presentada sería la indicada.